# Сортировка пузырьком массива имен java

Tags: java

```
public class Runner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BubbleSort bubbleSort = new BubbleSort();
    String [] massive = {"Gena", "Vasya", "Petya", "Katya"};

    bubbleSort.sort(massive);
  }
}

public class BubbleSort {

  public void sort(String[] arr){

    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0  ; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]){
                String temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
  }
}
```

Comment: Как сделать такой пример через пузырьковую сортировку ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется для строк это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
public class BubbleSort {
    public void sort(String[] arr) {
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[j + 1]) > 0) {
                    String temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```